# My async task is not accessible inside a popup alert in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, popup

I have made an popup alert for forgot password..I have to call an api call for forgot password,I had made it,All is working well,but thing is that i want to call that api call for forgot password on click of thath popup alert's "send" button..But it displays an error..that this asynctask can't accessible here..!

My code is as below:

**login.java**

```
package com.epe.yehki.ui;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.epe.yehki.backend.BackendAPIService;

import com.epe.yehki.backend.BackendAPIService;
import com.epe.yehki.backend.LoginAPI;
import com.epe.yehki.modelclasses.LoginResponceModelClass;
import com.epe.yehki.servercommunication.AsyncTaskCompleteListener;
import com.epe.yehki.servercommunication.MyAsyncTask;
import com.epe.yehki.servercommunication.YehkiNameValuePairs;
import com.epe.yehki.uc.Menu;
import com.epe.yehki.util.Const;
import com.epe.yehki.util.Pref;
import com.epe.yehki.util.Utils;
import com.example.yehki.R;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    public LoginAPI loginAPI;
    private EditText email;
    private EditText password;
    private TextView signup;
    private TextView forgot;
    private Button login;
    private ImageView ivRemember;
    public com.epe.yehki.uc.Menu loginmenu;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    public boolean flag = false;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String status;
    int flag1;
    static EditText et_email;
    private EditText popEmail;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_username);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_pwd);
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        ivRemember = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_remember);
        loginmenu = (Menu) findViewById(R.id.menuLogin);
        signup = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_sign_up);
        forgot = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_fgt_pwd);

        loginmenu.setSelectedTab(1);

        // CREATE ACCOUNT CLICK EVENT..!!
        signup.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegistrationActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
                finish();
            }
        });

        // REMEMBER ME CLICK EVENT...!
        ivRemember.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (flag) {
                    ivRemember.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.untic);
                    Pref.setValue(LoginActivity.this, Const.PREF_REMEMBER_ME, "0");
                    flag = false;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("checkbox check");
                    ivRemember.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tic);
                    Pref.setValue(LoginActivity.this, Const.PREF_REMEMBER_ME, "1");
                    flag = true;
                }

            }
        });
        // LOGIN CLICHK EVENT...

        login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!email.getText().toString().equals("") && email.getText().toString() != null) {
                    if ((!password.getText().toString().equals("") && password.getText().toString() != null)) {

                        if (Utils.isOnline(LoginActivity.this)) {
                            // Call AsyncTask For loginUser.
                            callAsyncLoginUser();
                        }

                    } else {
                        validation(getResources().getString(R.string.msg_password));
                        password.requestFocus();

                    }
                } else {
                    validation(getResources().getString(R.string.msg_enter_email));
                    email.requestFocus();
                }
            }
        });
        // FORGOT PASSWORD....!!!

    }

    void validation(String msg) {

        Utils.showCustomeAlertValidation(LoginActivity.this, msg, "Alert", "OK");
    }

    // RESPONSE lISTENER...................!!

    // *************************************************************************************************
    /**
     * CallAsyncTask for getting responc of countryList.
     */
    private void callAsyncLoginUser() {

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> argumentsList = YehkiNameValuePairs.getLoginNVPair(email.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());
        MyAsyncTask loginAsyncTask = new MyAsyncTask(this, Const.API_LOGIN, argumentsList);

        loginAsyncTask.execute();

        loginAsyncTask.setOnResultsListener(new AsyncTaskCompleteListener() {

            @Override
            public void onResultsSucceeded(String result, int asyncTaskNo) {
                Log.i("RegestrationActivity", "Result ================= " + result);
                LoginResponceModelClass userLoginResponce = parseUserLoginResponce(result);
                if (userLoginResponce != null) {

                    if (userLoginResponce.status.equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {

                        Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                        Pref.setValue(LoginActivity.this, Const.PREF_CUSTOMER_ID, userLoginResponce.customer.get(0).customer_id);
                        Pref.setValue(LoginActivity.this, Const.PREF_CUSTOMER_NAME, userLoginResponce.customer.get(0).customer_name);
                        Pref.setValue(LoginActivity.this, Const.PREF_USER_EMAIL, userLoginResponce.customer.get(0).email);

                        // i.putExtra("mail",
                        // userLoginResponce.customer.get(0).email);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();

                    }

                }
            }
        });

    }

    // **********************************************************************************************************
    /**
     * Function for Storing the data into model class using gson library.
     * 
     * @param result
     * @return
     */
    private LoginResponceModelClass parseUserLoginResponce(String result) {
        try {
            GsonBuilder gsonb = new GsonBuilder();
            Gson gson = gsonb.create();
            LoginResponceModelClass responce = gson.fromJson(result, LoginResponceModelClass.class);
            return responce;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * FORGOT PASSWORD API CALL............!!!!
     * 
     * 
     */

    // FORGOT PASSWORD POPUP...!!!

    public static void showCustomeAlertValidation(final Context context, String leftButton) {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.forgot_password);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

        et_email = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.et_mail);
        final Button send = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_send);

        send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new ForgotPassword().execute();
                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * FORGOT PASSWORD API CALL
     */
    public class ForgotPassword extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
            System.out.println("==========inside preexecute===================");

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            String forgetURL = Const.API_FORGOT_PASSWORD + "?email=" + et_email.getText().toString();

            BackendAPIService sh = new BackendAPIService();
            System.out.println(":::::::::::::forget url:::::::::::;" + forgetURL);
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(forgetURL, BackendAPIService.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
            System.out.println("=============MY RESPONSE==========" + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    if (jsonObj.has(Const.TAG_STATUS)) {
                        status = jsonObj.getString(Const.TAG_STATUS);
                        {
                            if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                                flag1 = 1;
                            } else {
                                flag1 = 2;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            if (flag1 == 1) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Forgot password link has been sent to your mail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            } else {
                Utils.showCustomeAlertValidation(LoginActivity.this, "Invalid Credentials", "Yehki", "OK");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Which line of your code is raising that error ?

Comment: this line "new ForgotPassword().execute();".....it says "NO enclosing instance of type LoginActivity is accessible"..

Comment: I think you're calling non-static method `public class ForgotPassword` from your static method. Can you remove `static` from `showCustomeAlertValidation` ?

Comment: ohh.....how silly mistake....nyways thank you so much friend..:)

Comment: I will add it as an answer and please accept it. So, other people can reference in the future. :)

Comment: Sure...Ye Lin....i will do it...just post it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're calling non-static method `public class ForgotPasswor`d from your static method.

Removing `static` from `showCustomeAlertValidation` should solve your problem.